# Cron Job doesnt start when DeploymentConfig in __construct parameter

Tags: magento2, cron

i have one Problem that i cant understand. I have a Cronjob that should read in the Env.php via DeploymentConfig. When i add DeploymentConfig in the Job __construct, the Job wont start.

Doesnt start:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    MarketCollectionFactory $marketCollectionFactory,
    MarketFactory $marketFactory,
    SynchronizableFactory $modelFactory,
    ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
    array $data = [],
    DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig
) {
        ~~~
}
```

Does start:

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    MarketCollectionFactory $marketCollectionFactory,
    MarketFactory $marketFactory,
    SynchronizableFactory $modelFactory,
    ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
    array $data = []
) {
        ~~~
}
```

Could it be, that i cant inject it in Cron Jobs. If yes, is there an other way to access the env.php?

Greetings

Edit:

Here is the full file:

```
namespace Addons\Markets\cron;
use Addons\Markets\Block\Markets;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Addons\Markets\Model\ResourceModel\Markets\CollectionFactory as MarketCollectionFactory;
use \Addons\Markets\Model\MarketFactory as MarketFactory;
use \Addons\Synchronizer\Model\SynchronizableFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use \Magento\Framework\App\DeploymentConfig;

use \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream;
use \Zend\Log\Logger;

class Job
{

private $market;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    MarketCollectionFactory $marketCollectionFactory,
    MarketFactory $marketFactory,
    SynchronizableFactory $modelFactory,
    ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
    array $data = [],
    DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig
) {
        $this->market = new Markets(
        $context,
        $marketCollectionFactory, 
        $marketFactory, 
        $modelFactory, 
        $resourceConnection,
        $data, 
        $deploymentConfig);
}

public function execute()
{
    $writer = new Stream(BP . '/var/log/cron.log');
    $logger = new Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info('Job Started');
    $this->market->synchronize();
}
}
```

Comment: What data do you want from env.php?

Comment: I have a part with information to access an extern backend. It looks like:

...
    'sync' => [
        'url' => 'ZZZ',
        'user' => 'YYY',
        'pw' => 'XXX'
    ],
...

Comment: Please post whole code for file

Comment: I edited the main post. I've tested the synchronize Code in a Controller and it works. Also i tested the Code without the DeploymentConfig. As soon the DeploymentConfig is in the Constructor, the Job wouldnt start. In the the exception.log is no entry about this.

Comment: @user3541236 have you also check with the correct order of parameters mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct the order of the parameters. `$data` is optional and has a default and must therefor be in the last place

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    MarketCollectionFactory $marketCollectionFactory,
    MarketFactory $marketFactory,
    SynchronizableFactory $modelFactory,
    ResourceConnection $resourceConnection,
    DeploymentConfig $deploymentConfig,
    array $data = []
) {
        ~~~
}
```

Comment: I think that was the problem. I changed the order and it works. Thank you!